# D3 - Project a single XY coordinate (Equirectangular) into a Orthographic coordinate

Tags: javascript, d3.js, maps, gis, projection

I'm trying to project a screen/pixel coordinate from an Equirectangular image into an Orthographic coordinate using D3 and it's projection tools (which I hardly understand).

I've found an example that shows how to do this using an interpolation animation to show the results but I can't understand how to achieve the same effect without rendering any canvas/svg while projecting a single coordinate.

https://observablehq.com/@d3/orthographic-to-equirectangular

All I need is to use the calculation D3 does to such coordinates to fix the distortion generated by the Equirectangular image in a different process, where I loop for each pixel in the equirectangular image to convert it into an "undistorted" one.

[Here's a picture of what I'm trying to achieve.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/id4eY.png)

My code looks something like this:

```
// Equirectangular image source size

var width = $("#equirectangular_image").width(); // 1024
var height = $("#equirectangular_image").height(); // 512


// Screen XY into LATLON - 512 and 256 are just an example representing the center of the image.

// This was wrong 
// var offsetX = 512 / width * 360;
// var offsetY = 256 / height * 180;

// Edited
var offsetX = 512;
var offsetY = 256;

var projectionOrtho = d3.geoOrthographic();
var projectionEqui = d3.geoEquirectangular();


var ortho_coords = projectionOrtho([offsetX,offsetY]);
var fixed_coords = projectionEqui(ortho_coords);

// fixed_coords isn't returning the expected coordinates
```

Please, help! Thanks!

*PS: I'm looking for a solution to the main topic which is to fix the distortion generated by the equirectangular image. If there's a better approach to do this without using any external libraries I'd be glad to go down that road.*

Comment: `offsetX ` and `offsetY` are not proper coordinate values to pass to a projection, you need to have [long,lat] points to pass to a projection so that the projection function return a proper [x,y] screen pixel values. can you elaborate more about what you want to have? is it [x, y] pixel value ortho_coords to be converted to [long,lat] fixed_coords? or is it [long,lat] geoOrthographic to be converted to [long,lat] geoOrthographic?

Comment: @mamoun-othman thanks for your reply. What I'm trying to do is to fix the distortion generated by the Equirectangular image. I realized that my approach was wrong because D3 uses pixel coordinates instead of angle of rotation. Here you can see what I'm trying to do https://i.imgur.com/CiU2lBJ.png